# GetWindowTextLength() returns 0, supposedly because of invalid window handle

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to build a simple graph plotting application with C and Windows API for studying purposes. It is supposed to take user's input containing a math function of one real variable and then to plot it. I tried to implement user's input capabilities by creating textbox and submit button through calling CreateWindow() from the callback window function. However, when I attempted to test the textbox by evaluating input text size, I received 0 under any conditions (I also made sure that it is not an ASCII/UNICODE issue). GetLastError() got 1400 error code, i.e. invalid window handle. What could be possible reasons for this error and why respective window handle is considered invalid?

I'm using Bloodshed Dev-C++ 5.11 on Windows 10 x64 with 64-bit TDM-GCC 4.9.2.

Please find below the piece of callback function that is causing problems:

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        int len;
        (...other declarations go here...)
        HWND text_box; 
        HWND plot_button;

        switch (message){ 
            case WM_CREATE:
                text_box = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                       "",
                                       WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                       10, 5, 390, 20,
                                       hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
                plot_button = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                             "Plot",
                             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                             420, 5, 165, 20,
                             hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
                break;

            case WM_COMMAND:
                switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
                    case 1: 
                        len = GetWindowTextLength(text_box); 
                        printf("%d", len); // a simple console output for testing purposes only, returns 0 disregarding the text length
                    (...other irrelevant code...)
                    break;
                }
            break;
         (...other irrelevant code...)
    }
```

Comment: Why `text_box`  is local variable ? Every time window procedure is called this variable is created, so when `WM_COMMAND` message is processed this var is uninitialized. Make it `static` and try again.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to say solved. If you want, you can add an answer. Although this is a dupe many times over so I don't think it will help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [a comment by rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398499/getwindowtextlength-returns-0-supposedly-because-of-invalid-window-handle#comment101278517_57398499):

You need to make `text_box` `static`. Every time the window procedure is called this variable is created, so when the `WM_COMMAND` message is processed this variable is uninitialized.

To make `text_box` `static`, do this:

```
static HWND text_box;
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that `WndProc()` would then only be usable for 1 parent `HWND` at a time. If you needed to make multiple instances of the parent widow, each with their own text box, the alternative would be to assign an ID number to the text box when creating it with `CreateWindow()` (change `(HMENU) 0` to `(HMENU) IDNumber`), and then the `WM_COMMAND` handler could use [`GetDlgItem()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) to get the calling parent's text box `HWND` from that ID: `GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDNumber))`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not a Windows expert by any means. Please ask rafix07 (and feel free to edit, this is Community Wiki, after all).